# Issue to read multiple barcodes using zxing library

Tags: java, image, image-processing, zxing

I am trying to read 2D Data matrix barcode using zxing library(GenericMultipleBarcodeReader). I have multiple barcodes on a single image.

> The problem is that the efficiency of the zing reader is very low, it
>   recognizes 1 barcode from image 1.png and no barcode from image 2.png which has 48 barcodes. Is there
>   any way to get 100% efficiency or any other library which results 100%

My code to read barcode is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("1.png"));
        if (image != null) {
            LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

            DataMatrixReader dataMatrixReader = new DataMatrixReader();

            Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
            hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

            GenericMultipleBarcodeReader reader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(
                    dataMatrixReader);
            Result[] results = reader.decodeMultiple(bitmap, hints);

            for (Result result : results) {
                System.out.println(result.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

And images I used are:

[image: 1.png]
[image: 2.jpg]

**Please help to resolve this issue.**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't quite work this way. It will not read barcodes in a grid, as it makes an assumption that it can cut up the image in a certain way that won't be compatible with grids. You will have to write your own method to cut up the image into scannable regions.

It is also the case that the Data Matrix decoder assumes the center of the image is inside the barcode. This is another reason you need to pre-chop the image into squares around the cylinders and then scan. It ought to work fairly well then.

Comment: @Sean-Thanks for responding, Please tell me is the angle of the barcode may also be an issue to read the barcode?

Comment: It should be able to scan at all those angles, but, it's going to work better when it's upright.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to consider a barcode engine that can detect multiple barcodes in various orientations on one document. If you're running on Windows, the [ClearImage Barcode SDK](http://www.inliteresearch.com/barcode-recognition/) has a Java API and should be able to handle your needs without pre-processing. You can test if their engine can read your image using their [Online Barcode Reader](http://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/).

Some sample code:

```
public static void testDataMatrix () {
  try { 
       String filename  = "1.png ";
       CiServer objCi = new CiServer();
       Ci = objCi.getICiServer();

       ICiDataMatrix reader = Ci.CreateDataMatrix(); // read DataMatrix Barcode
       reader.getImage().Open(filename, 1);
       int n = reader.Find(0); // find all the barcodes in the doc
       for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          ICiBarcode Bc = reader.getBarcodes().getItem(i); // getItem is 1-based
          System.out.println("Barcode " + i + " has Text: " + Bc.getText());
       }
   } catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
 }
```

Disclaimer: I've done some work for Inlite in the past.