# Zxing Datamatrix code scanning

Tags: ios, zxing

I am using the zxing datamatrix code scanner in iOS, and there seems to be a bug that makes it so that the code must be in the exact center of the screen in order to read.  As I slide the code closer to the center, it will scan somewhere very close to the exact center of the screen.

For my app's purposes, the datamatrix code might be in the center, but also might be anywhere else in the visible part of the image.

Can anyone explain this?  Has anyone fixed this? For reference, zxing can scan qr codes anywhere in the visible image.

This will scan:

[image: This will scan]

This will not scan...

[image: This wont scan]

Comment: I don't know enough about this to make any real suggestions but I believe QR codes have the identifying corners (3 target looking squares) to help identify what angle, location and scale the the Qr is. Does this `datamatrix` have similar markings?

Comment: Yes, datamatrix uses the solid black "L" shape in one corner, and alternating white and black spots in the other corner

Comment: Did u check that post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721077/issue-to-read-multiple-barcodes-using-zxing-library? it looks like ur barcode need to be at the center of ur image. Is there a way you can crop your image so that ur barcode is at the center?

Comment: Yes thank you.  According to Sean Owen, "[ZXing] Data Matrix decoder assumes the center of the image is inside the barcode." So it appears I would have to crop the image to read it.  This wont work unless I know where the DM is in the image though