# zxing :unable to read barcode which is a part of a larger image

Tags: java, zxing

i am using javase package of zxing. In my images barcodes are actually a part of a larger image. When i provide those images as it is then zxing is unable to read the barcode but if i crop the image to just the barcode then zxing runs just fine. Is there some possible way to make zxing recognise the barcode in large images as well without me providing it the barcode coordinates.

Thank You

as an example consider these 2 images - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/heyid7mwkljrhdb/A4aFanT7Vg

Comment: I don't have an answer but hope this post helps you:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12721976/259889

Comment: any news on this? I'm having issues even when the barcode is ~1/8th total size of page, but in top-left corner

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to read this image. Some just won't decode by chance. You should try using `TRY_HARDER` mode hint if you are decoding on a desktop computer. Also try swapping out a different `Binarizer`.

Comment: when does a `Binarizer` come into play for decoding QR codes? I haven't seen that in examples